# Send email when Google Form submission is updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have read plenty of posts about notifying someone via email when a form has been submitted and including the form data in the email but what I would like to do is identify an update to already existing information and have that put in an email and sent. I imagine that this would be done by identifying the latest timestamp and grabbing the corresponding entry. However, my extremely limited programming skills mean that I have been unable to work out the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just happens I have such a function in my bag of tricks!

This function assumes that you've got a trigger function `formSubmitted(e)` for form submission that utilizes the event object it receives. As you surmised, it identifies the most recent update. It then creates a simulated form submission event, and invokes the form submission trigger function.

Set `onChange()` up to trigger on spreadsheet changes.

```js
/**
 * Sometimes, Google Apps Script sucks. This is one of those times.
 * If a user updates previously submitted form data by using the "edit" link,
 * that data will be updated in the Form Responses sheet. Unfortunately,
 * that will NOT generate a spreadsheet form submission event. (See explanation:
 * https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2969#c12)
 *
 * Observation: a form edit shows up as a change, with type of "OTHER", and source
 * of a spreadsheet with activeSheet="Form Responses" and activeRange="A1". We
 * will use that information to limit when we force our normal form-submission
 * handler to run. Unfortunately, the event doesn't tell us which row changed,
 * but that should be the one with the most recent timeStamp. 
 */
function onChange( e ) {
  if (e.changeType !== "OTHER") return;
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName().indexOf("Form Responses") === -1) return;
  if (e.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation() !== "A1") return;

  // Find latest form submission
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var timeStamps = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();

  // Determine most recent date
  var max = Math.max.apply(null,transpose(timeStamps)[0]);
  var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var lastMax = properties.getProperty("maxDate");
  if (lastMax && max.toString() === lastMax) return; // Avoid changes triggered by updates from onChange function
  Logger.log("onChange() thinks there's been a form edit. e="+JSON.stringify(e));
  properties.setProperty("maxDate", max.toString());
  var maxDate=new Date(max);

  // Then find the sheet row that contains it
  for (var row=0,found=false;row<timeStamps.length&&!found;row++) {
    if (timeStamps[row][0] && timeStamps[row][0].getTime() === maxDate.getTime()) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    // We're blind... recalc everything
    // TODO
  }
  else {
    // Trigger the submission event for this row
    row += 2; // adjust for offset into sheet rows
    var dataRange= sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var headers = data[0];
    var response = data[row];
    var respRange = dataRange.offset(row-1, 0, 1, dataRange.getLastColumn());

    // Build event object with range, values and namedValues filled in
    var values = respRange.getValues()[0];
    var namedValues = {};
    for (var h in headers) { namedValues[headers[h]] = [values[h]]; } 
    var e = { range: respRange,
              values: values,
              namedValues: namedValues
            };
     formSubmitted(e);        // Simulate event
  }
}
```

Comment: Now that I have applied myself to the task I have found that this does indeed work. Great solution. It seems that I can only mark one answer correct but both answers worked and probably have their benefits and drawbacks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Google App Script, open Spreadsheet where your form responses are being stored. 
Go to Tools -> Script Editor -> Script editor will be opened, copy the below function.

Create a trigger to call this function on form submission
Resources -> Current project's triggers -> Select 'from spreadsheet' and 'On form submit' and create a trigger.

```
function sendEmailNoti(e) {
   var timeStamp = e.values[0];
   var userEmail = e.values[1];
   var products = e.values[2];

   var subject = "New Subscription Request";
   var email = "abcd@yourdomain.com";
   var message = "User email : " + userEmail + "<BR>Products opted : " + products + "<BR>Timestamp : " + timeStamp;


   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: email,
     subject: subject,
     htmlBody: message
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Uttam. This seems to be a simple solution that works. Is it possible to have information included in the email that has not changed. E.G., if an edit is made the userEmail may stay the same but the email will not appear in the message in these instances. Also, is it possible to get the form Edit URL in to the message (getEditUrl())?

Answer (score 0):

I approached this problem slightly differently. Instead of creating a new trigger - modified the form submit trigger itself slightly to pick values for each key from the spreadsheet instead of from the form responses.

The revised code looks like this

```
// Include a copy of all responses
for ( var keys in columns ) {
  var key = columns[keys];
  message += key + ' :: '+ sheet.getRange(resultUrls.length+1, (data[0].indexOf(key)+1)).getValues() + "<br />";
}
```